# How can I make my code actually save user input to a csv file?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

So here's my problem - I'm trying to write a program that will save user input to a csv file. Simple, right? Well, I'm quite new to programming and I can't for the life of me figure out where I'm going wrong, because it's not saving the user input. I'm sure the answer is incredibly easy, but I've tried and tried and can't figure it out, so would anyone mind just pointing me to where I'm going wrong?
PS: sorry for poor quality of code and any other things like that - I'm learning as fast as I can!

Here's my code so far:

```
import csv
def inputdata():
    openingfile = open('weatherdata.csv', 'w', newline='')
    w = csv.writer(openingfile)  

    while True:
        temperature = input("Enter temperature: ")  
        windspeed = input("Enter windspeed: ")  


        save = input("Would you like to save? Y/N: ")  
        if save.lower() == "y":
            w.writerow([temperature, windspeed])  
            print("---Your data has been saved---")

        
        elif save.lower() == "n":
            print("Program closed.")
            openingfile.close()
            exit()
        
inputdata()
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior in [my Repl.it](https://repl.it/@esqew/FarflungWelllitComputers) - seems to write on close after "N" input from user. Is this not what you expected?

Comment: Tiny(!) nitpick (and not anything to worry about now), but in the future: especially for [tag:python] questions, ensure that your indentation in the snippets you post match *exactly* to what you're working with. You previously had an extra whitespace character before your `inputdata()` call, which was throwing an `IndentationError` when copy/pasted into my IDE. I've taken the liberty of editing your question to reflect what appears to be your intention here.

Comment: How are you running the code and where do you expect the csv to appear?

Comment: While also slightly tangential, in a similar vein: don't fret about "*poor quality of code*" here - we see thousands of questions a day with worse! What's more, as long as your question is intelligible (i.e., you're asking a distinct, answerable question in line with the [How to Ask guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)) you're a-ok.

Comment: thanks guys - to answer your first thing esqew then I haven't been able to make it write anything to a csv file, all it does is make the file itself, with no data inside, no matter what I put as the answer to the Y/N question

Comment: Likewise Axe319 - I'm running my code through the file it is written in, and thus input is entered through the IDE. Also I would expect the csv to appear in the folder in which my code is saved, and the empty csv file (see above) has indeed appeared here.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
def inputdata():

    with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        w = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
        save = "y"
        while save == "y":
            temperature = input("Enter temperature: ")  
            windspeed = input("Enter windspeed: ")  


            save = input("Would you like to save? Y/N: ")  
            if save.lower() == "y":
                w.writerow([temperature, windspeed])   
                print("---Your data has been saved---")

            save = input("Would you like make another entry? Y/N: ")

        print("Program closed.")

inputdata()
```

Comment: this is absolutely perfect - just what I was looking for! If you are reading this finding yourself with the same issue as I had, then this is just what you need.

Comment: @Jonesy19 Happy to hear that!

Answer (score -2):

you should try as much as possible to use context manager `(with open)` when reading files. This will make sure to close any open files in the event you forget to manually close. For your query, check this write up from source: [read/write csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
     # reading the file
     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
     for row in spamreader:
        print(', '.join(row))
     # writing
     spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
```

Comment: This does not address anything in the context of the original post, and might be confusing for someone of OP's skill level.

Comment: yes sorry james - I'm afraid I'm not quite at the standard yet of this, but obviously it will be useful to me in the future, I would have thought

Comment: which is why I directed them to read the docs, which can be complemented by reading/checking out fileIO operations